# find the middle alphabet from two letter input got incorrect result

Tags: javascript

i have this function to find the middle alphabet from two letter input, but it got incorrect result

```js
const findMiddleAlphabet = (firstLetter, lastLetter) => {
    const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        alphabetArr = [...alphabet];
    let alphabetRange = alphabetArr.slice(alphabetArr.indexOf(firstLetter), alphabetArr.indexOf(lastLetter));

    if (!alphabetRange.length) return '';

    let mid = alphabetRange.length / 2;
    if (alphabetRange.length % 2 === 1) {
        return alphabetRange[Math.floor(mid)];
    } else {
        return [
            alphabetRange[mid - 1],
            alphabetRange[mid],
        ].join('');
    }
}

 console.log(findMiddleAlphabet('Q', 'U'));
 console.log(findMiddleAlphabet('R', 'U'));
```

my output is:

> RS
> S

the expected output is:

> S
> ST

what is wrong please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just slicing the array at the wrong index. When you do `myArr.slice(5, 10)`, it contains elements `myArr[5] ~ myArr[9]`, so you need to add `1` to the second index.

```js
const findMiddleAlphabet = (firstLetter, lastLetter) => {
  const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    alphabetArr = [...alphabet];
  //here, you need to put +1 on the second index because slice omits that element.
  let alphabetRange = alphabetArr.slice(alphabetArr.indexOf(firstLetter), 
                                        alphabetArr.indexOf(lastLetter) + 1);

  if (!alphabetRange.length) return '';

  let mid = alphabetRange.length / 2;
  if (alphabetRange.length % 2 === 1) {
    return alphabetRange[Math.floor(mid)];
  } else {
    return [
      alphabetRange[mid - 1],
      alphabetRange[mid],
    ].join('');
  }
}

console.log(findMiddleAlphabet('Q', 'U'));
console.log(findMiddleAlphabet('R', 'U'));
```